# Visual Studio 2017 fails to install offline with "Unable to download installation files"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, offline, visual-studio-2017

So I've created an offline installed of VS 2017 Community on my laptop using this command:

> **vs_community.exe** --layout "D:\Downloads\VS Community 2017" --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor Component.WebSocket Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.0

When I transfer the setup files onto my corporate PC (which is behind a firewall) and run the "vs_community.exe" setup file, all I get is this error. There's no way to bypass the corporate firewall or to make exceptions. How do I install VS 2017 offline? Am I missing something here?

[image]

**Edit:** I have installed VS 2017 on my laptop keeping the internet connection active. Then when I disconnect the internet on my laptop and try installing again, the installer launches! So perhaps there are some dependencies missing on my corporate PC that are now installed on my laptop?

**Edit:** The above command installs .NET, .NET core, Xamarin, Node.js, TypeScript and C++ for Mobile. The total downloaded size is 13.2 GB.

Comment: I hope [Microsoft`s recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio) will help you.
If comand of exe creating was successed, offline installer should not try to use the internet connection.

Comment: I just used this webpage and followed the "For .NET web and .NET desktop development" options. Worked well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It worked!! All I had to do was install the certificates into the root CA! Something I missed noticing in the VS 2017 docs:

> How to install from the offline installation folder
>
> 1. **Install the certificates** (They are in the "certificates" folder, which is in your Layout folder. )
> 2. Simply right-click each one and choose Install PFX.
> 3. Specify Local machine (not current user)
> 4. You can use an empty password
> 5. Run the installation file. For example, run:
>      c:\vs2017offline\vs_enterprise.exe
>
> --- [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio#how-to-customize-your-offline-%20installer)

**Edit:** Remember to install the certs using the Admin account on the PC, or it won't work...

Comment: This didn't help for me. All certificates installed but error still shows.

Comment: @Zitrax, I know this is a month later, but make sure that if you are logged in as a user, but running the installer with a separate admin account, that you install the certificates to the certstore for the admin account.

Comment: @JaimeStill thanks a lot! I wish Microsofts install instructions would have mentioned that. ( I logged in as admin, right clicked the certificates and installed them, then logged back in as my user and it started to install. )

Comment: The issue for me was the certificates, but using the batch file suggested by the Microsoft Docs link from @Harsh did not work, when using the already installed `certmgr`. Double clicking each certificate that was a part of the download, and going through the installation wizard, resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. It's rare that I find a 'solution' to something like this first time but this was one.

Comment: I could not find certificates and layout folder, please let me know where  I can find it?

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution will work if you have an internet connection. You need internet connection anyway, in some cases you may need to check windows firewall too.

Comment: @AdityaBokade, You can find certificates folder in "D:\Downloads\VS Community 2017" when you run command in cmd like this "vs_community.exe --layout "D:\Downloads\VS Community 2017" --lang en-US"

Answer (score 4):

Please try to follow this steps:

1. Right click on exe file.
2. Select "Properties".
3. Click on the "Digital Signatures" tab. Now you can see "signature list".
4. Select signature
5. Click on "Details" button.
6. Click on "View certificate" button
7. Click on "Install certificate" and follows installation wizard

All certificates within "signature list" should be installed. I use Windows 10.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I'm getting the error message above when I follow all the instructions on the Microsoft recommendations page EgoPingvina mentioned above. The bootstrap installer for VS_Community 2017 won't even download the layout. Please help, I've been on this for a week now. I'm using windows 10 pro.

Comment: I continued this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286592/visual-studio-2017-cant-install?noredirect=1#comment75580047_44286592
For those who still with problems (like me :c)

Answer (score 3):

Was doing this for VS Community 2017 and it would install everything and it does the core installation without any trouble.  However, if i select to install the universal or .Net development portions it will install it almost completely, but it will fail on two files. It will say that it cannot download the files from the internet. The files exist in the installation directory and I even went and downloaded the files and placed them into the appropriate directories and it still thinks that it needs to download those two files preventing me from completing the installation process. If I just continue it will install everything else except those two files. I've tried this with a few different layout downloads in different forms (ISO, directory, etc) and same issue (so it isn't a bad download or anything, and I'm sure I did that all correctly).  The two files are:

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10983757/f8c877406947fdc71ed2dd9127d2f9fa/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualstudio.interactivecomponents.resources.vsix

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/11347028/25bedee219940beceecab91dac231235/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.testplatform.legacy.core.resources.vsix

If I plug myself online and do a repair it will go grab those two files without having to grab everything else, but it kind of defeats the purpose.  Don't expect a solution, but wanted to mention it because all the other problems are related to installing the certs and I can't find anything online about it failing on just a few files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was related to **CNG key isolation windows service**, it was disabled, the solution mentioned in below link:

[Visual Studio 2017 - Can't install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286592/visual-studio-2017-cant-install?noredirect=1#comment75580047_44286592)

Comment: If this service is disabled, even web installer will fail. I spent whole day googling only to find tips about importing certificates and then your comment happened.

Answer (score 1):

How i solved mine.

1. I downloaded the setup helper from Microsoft website (i downloaded the enterprise installer, because that's the offline installer version i have )
2. I ran the program, and it wanted to download the complete setup, so i cancelled it
3. I ran my offline installer (vs_Enterprise.exe)
4. Then it fixed the issue.
5. I disconnected the internet, and continued with the offline installation

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue **after uninstalling SSDT for Visual studio 2017**, ***Can't  remove and reinstall or update visual studio 2017***.
I just restart my machine and it's OK.
my be you have also to log in as an administrator ( it depends on your machine configuration and what you can do with you current account)

Answer (score -2):

*Edited to avoid misunderstand*

Running the downloaded Visual Studio layout as administrator worked for me. 
Maybe the *VS_Version.exe* try to normally download the files because it can't access to files in the layout (sometimes named *backup*), like me, in my job we have a lot of restrictions and when I ran the VS_version.exe tried to download and get the message error, but when I ran again the .exe as Administrator the installer started normaly, getting the files from the *backup* folder

Comment: You obviously don't have to download on each PC! Download on one and use an external SATA HDD to transfer among PCs or using corporate network!!

Comment: Ok, I think people misunderstand me ... I downloaded it once, maybe I should edit my answer to avoid misunderstandings.