# Visual Studio 2017 - Can't install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2017 Community because the last version i had, was a pre-Release of the same version. But now i can't keep using the program because it forces me to update to a new one.

[image: The problem]

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829675/visual-studio-2017-fails-to-install-offline-with-unable-to-download-installatio) with a similar problem but the answer didn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: If all fails can't you download an ISO version which wouldn't require to download files from MS?

Comment: I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio for an offline instalation of VS2017, but the link doesn't work. Any idea where can i get those files?

Comment: Why don't you connect to the network?

Comment: I'm already connected to the network.....

Comment: Tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-in-offline-environment ?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** The problem can be in optimized (tweaked) system. Enable services that was originally on.

### Read log file

If you are sure that there is no any of [internet](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8677e70c-4dc6-4b53-8eef-544563048cea/downloading-visual-studio-2017-offline-installer?forum=vssetup) / [firewall](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2017dc4e-6f75-42f5-9c65-3a107e8ce547/caught-exception-type-cryptographicexception-message-there-are-no-more-endpoints-available?forum=visualstudiogeneral) issues, all updates are installed (to meet [requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs), especially for [.NET Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/issues/591)), then you should check log file in `%TEMP%` directory.
A path something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_bootstrapper_<date and time of last run>.log`.

I'd expect, that it says:

> Verifying signature
>
> Caught Exception: Type = CryptographicException, Message = There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper

### Fix cryptographic exception

The first step is to [install the certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42829675/1104612).

If the error still there, then check system services (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `services.msc`). Go through all list, read descriptions and search for *certificates*, *private and public keys*. I started **CNG key isolation** service (KeyIso) and magically the installer became normal.

---

Also I think this [Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) can be useful for everyone who did upgrade from previous version (2013, 2015) like me.

Comment: It worked after activating CNG key isolation service, I don't know how it was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue which you are facing. 
As a troubleshooting,I found that now a days, files download from aka.ms.
Due to some reason you might not be reachable from your machine.

To find out issue, you should first run fiddler and then start installation of Visual studio 2017. Find from where your exe is trying to download file for installation.

Once you could find URL like I got "aka.ms". Try to ping on that domain to verify connection and then try to open that URL from your computer.

If everything will be fine as I have explained your setup will download files.

Another Problem may be you have to install all the certificates as shown below:

1. Right click on exe file.
2. Select "Properties".
3. Click on the "Digital Signatures" tab.
4. Now you can see "signature list".
5. Select signature Click on "Details" button.
6. Click on "View certificate" button Click on "Install certificate" and follows installation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Check internet connection, chck if you have any vpn/proxy, check if you have any wierd anti-virus, windows firewall or some external, run windows update (just in case), if these fail you will need to download the new version directly from [Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The log at %TEMP% showed a certificate problem .

Since the machine was an old windows 7, I had to **update IE8 to IE11** so the installer could download. It wasn't installing yet. I had to set IE security level from medium-high to medium.

The log was:

```
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:7/15/2020 12:32:35 PM: Download failed using WebClient engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Certificate is invalid: vs_installer.opc    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
```